# How does Java 8 know which String::compareTo method reference to use when sorting?

Tags: java-8, method-reference

How does Java know which `String::compareTo` method reference to use when calling `Collections.sort(someListOfStrings, String::compareTo);`? `compareTo` is not static and it needs to know the `value` of the "left hand side" of the comparison.

Comment: what is this `String::compareTo`

Comment: Your question is not clear: `Collections.sort` sorts the items of a collection, `String::compareTo` is used to compare two strings in that collection. if string a < string b then by doing `a.compareTo(b)` you'll get a negative result and `b.compareTo(a)` will return a positive result, either way - this result will be used to sort the items properly.

Comment: More detail here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/35914775/3333878

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose that you use method reference for `Comparator` interface:

```
Comparator<String> cmp = String::compareTo;
```

When you call the `cmp.compare(left, right)` (which is "single abstract method" or "SAM" of `Comparator` interface), the magic occurs:

```
int result = cmp.compare(left, right);
                           |     |
  /------------------------/     |
  |              /---------------/
  |              |
left.compareTo(right);
```

Basically all the parameters of SAM are converted to the parameters of the referred method, but `this` object (which is on the left side) is also counted as parameter.

Comment: This is called an *unbound instance* method reference.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev but how does `String::compareTo`'s type match `Comparator<String>`? The type signature doesn't match... `String`'s `compareTo` method is `public int compareTo(String anotherString)`, `Comparator<String>` is ` int compare(String o1, String o2);` I know I'm missing something I cant quite connect the dots.

Comment: @stantonk, think about `this` as about one more parameter, so `public int compareTo(String anotherString)` is like `public static int compareTo(String this, String anotherString)`. Generally in OOP-languages internally it works like this: the object pointer (reference) is converted to the first parameter of the function/method.

Comment: @TagirValeev A HAH! Yes yes, it makes sense now. Python makes this explicit in instance method signatures by always requiring `self` as the first parameter. It would have to be an implied parameter, since methods have to be bound somehow to the appropriate instance for them to be methods on a class instance and know to which `this` one was referring. Thanks!

Comment: @stantonk: note that Java 8 allows you to declare the `this` instance explicitly, if you prefer that, like `ReturnType instancemethod(MyType this, OtherParameterType arg1, …)`

Answer (score 0):

OK, the source of Collections.sort() looks as follows:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
   Object[] a = list.toArray();
   Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator)c);
   ListIterator i = list.listIterator();
   for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
      i.next();
      i.set(a[j]);
   }
}
```

I think it is quite clear now. The contents is a list. It means it has an order and the items are treated one by one in that order.

Comment: sorry, that does not answer my question. What I'm trying to understand is how Java knows to use the correct `String::compareTo` method reference for each element in the list to be sorted.

Comment: so, for instance, let's say you had a list `["c", "b", "a"]`. the first element in that list, "c", is an instance of the `String` class, which has a property of `value` that is a character array containing a single character, 'c'. `compareTo` makes a comparison between "c" and "b" deep inside the `Collections.sort` method, i.e. `if (c.compare(a[runHi++], a[lo]) < 0) `. I am not seeing how the method reference gets you from `Comparable` to `Comparator`.