# Java 8: Map instead of simple loop

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I am new in functional programming in java 1.8.
I have simple loop like the below code:

```
File folder = new File("./src/renamer/Newaudio");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Here is file number: " + i);
}
```

I am going to change the upper `for loop` to the functional format using the arrow function (like a lambda).

```
listOfFiles.map((file) = > {
        System.out.println("Here is file number: " + i);
});
```

Unfortunately, it complains with:

```
Cannot invoke map((<no type> file) -> {}) on the array type File[]
```

**Why i get this error?
 how i can resolve it?**

***I like to learn about Lambda, so i am not interested to the foreach***

Comment: Use `.forEach` instead of `.map`. Note that you can use `Files.list(Paths.get("./src/renamer/Newaudio")).forEach(...)` to jump into the Stream API directly.

Comment: What's `i` in your lambda?

Comment: If you're using Java 8, **Don't use the `File` class**. It's outdated and should be laid to rest. Use `Path` and `Files`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`folder.listFiles()` should be wrapped with the `Optional.ofNullable` to prevent from a `NullPointerException`. It can return `null` if the given pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

```
Stream.of(ofNullable(folder.listFiles()).
          orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("It's not a directory!")))
      .forEach(f -> {});
```

where the `forEach` method could take these arguments:

(1) an anonymous class

```
new Consumer<File>() {
    public @Override void accept(File file) {
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```

(2) expended lambda expressions

```
(File f) -> { System.out.println(f); }
(f) -> { System.out.println(f); }
```

(3) simplified lambda expressions

```
f -> { System.out.println(f); }
f -> System.out.println(f)
```

(4) a method reference

```
System.out::println
```

Comment: when i used the multiple line format of lambda **(f->{system.out.pringlin()})**  it complains that  

 Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
  Expression
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: @Salman: The `System` class starts with an upper case `S`, the method is `println`, not `pringlin`, and there has to be a semi-colon after the statement.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko: `forEach` (not `foerEach`) can take more than these four kind of arguments. A named class implementing `Consumer` works as well, as any other expression leading to an instance of that type, like reading a variable containing an existing instance or invoking a factory method. And you can pass `null`, the compiler won’t object, though the result is predictably of little use…

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) to print the file numbers only

```
    IntStream.range(0,listOfFiles.length).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or To print Content of array you can use

```
    Arrays.stream(listOfFiles).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Compiler will convert your method reference to
lambda expression at compile time so this

```
    Arrays.stream(listOfFiles).forEach(System.out::println);
```

will be converted into this

```
=>  Arrays.stream(listOfFiles).forEach(i->System.out.println(i));
```

With lambda you can use the expended lambda `{}` as well

```
=> Arrays.stream(listOfFiles).forEach(i->{
       if (!i.isHidden()) { // don't print hidden files
           System.out.println(i);               
       }
   });
```

So [`listFiles`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) returns `null` is file is not a directory and for simplicity you can simply put a check at the first place

```
    File folder = new File("./src/renamer/Newaudio");
    if (folder.isDirectory()) {
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        Arrays.stream(listOfFiles).forEach(i->System.out.println(i));           
    }
```

Reference

[Lambda and Method reference concise details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914775/java-8-difference-between-method-reference-bound-receiver-and-unbound-receiver)

Comment: I like to learn about Lambda, so i am not interested to the foreach

Comment: @Salman you seem to misunderstand what "Lambda" is. The lambda is the parameter of the `map` or `forEach` method, not the `map` method itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
IntStream.range(0, listOfFiles.length).forEach(file -> {
    System.out.println(file);
});
```

Comment: Note: OP's original code did not print the file names but just the numbers.