# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I read the tutorial for Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type . Here is the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

So I wrote my own code but I am  unable to remove error . 
`Arrays.sort(arr, String::compareToIgnoreCase);` is a legal statement 
but 
 `Consumer m2 =Myclass::doit;` gives an error . 
How to resolve this error ? Is the concept of **Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type** applicable to inbuilt classes of java like String ?

Here goes my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

interface Myinter {
 void doit(List<String> s);
}
public class Myclass implements Myinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
        obj.add("raj");
        obj.add("gopal");
        obj.add("bhallamudi");
        String arr[] = new String[obj.size()];
        arr = obj.toArray(arr);
        Arrays.sort(arr, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
        for (String s : arr)
            System.out.println(s + " ");

          Consumer<List<String>> m2 =Myclass::doit;
          m2.accept(obj);
    }
    @Override
    public void doit(List<String> s) {
            System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you create an unbound reference to an instance method, the receiver instance becomes the first functional argument.

In the case of `String::compareToIgnoreCase`, you will have two string arguments being passed to `Comparator.compare`; the method `compareToIgnoreCase` will be invoked on the first getting the second passed as argument.

Likewise, you would have to use

```
BiConsumer<Myclass,List<String>> m2 = Myclass::doit;
m2.accept(new MyClass(), obj);
```

as you can’t invoke the instance method `doit` without an instance of `Myclass`. Or, incorporating your interface:

```
BiConsumer<Myinter,List<String>> m2 = Myinter::doit;
m2.accept(new MyClass(), obj);
```

Here, an instance of any class implementing `Myinter` is sufficient.

Comment: @Holger "you can’t invoke the instance method doit without an instance of Myclass" Yes you are right . Thats why  MyClass instance is included in accept method . Now  consider this statement Arrays.sort(arr, String::compareToIgnoreCase). Is an instance of String class created automatically before calling the compareToIgnoreCase method ?

Comment: Myclass reallyMyClass = new Myclass();
Consumer<List<String>> m2 = reallyMyClass::doit;
m2.accept(obj); (or)                              
BiConsumer<Myinter,List<String>> m2 = Myinter::doit;
m2.accept(new MyClass(), obj); // both are creating instance of  MyClass.

Comment: @Raj Gopal Bhallamudi: no, the sort algorithm will always call the `Comparator.compare` method with two different elements of the array, as that’s the purpose of the comparator, to compare two elements. If the array has only one element or less, it will not call the comparator at all, as such an array can be considered to be already sorted.

Comment: @Holger . I did not understand "the method compareToIgnoreCase will be invoked on the first getting the second." please explain

Comment: `(first, second) -> first.compareToIgnoreCase(second)`

Comment: `reallyMyClass::doit` creates a *bound* reference, the method `doit` will always be invoked on the same object, which you provided with `reallyMyClass`. In contrast, `Myinter::doit` creates an *unbound* reference, which means, the method will be called on the instance provided as first argument to the `accept` method.

Comment: https://ideone.com/CMFUFr . here Comparator.compare method body will be replaced by userdefined  CompareFunction  . So no need for this concept in java 8 method reference - ContainingType::instancemethod .

Comment: @Raj Gopal Bhallamudi: I have no idea what you are trying to tell me with that. This is not the place to discuss whether there is a need for a concept or not. Here, you got an answer explaining this concept to you. Either, you understood now or you didn’t…

Comment: @holger everything is interrelated . compareToIgnoreCase is an instance method and String is a class.

Comment: @Raj Gopal Bhallamudi: are you still trying to solve your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46030110/2711488), i.e. trying to understand how unbound method references work, or just trying to entertain yourself by dropping irrelevant phrases without any actual goal?

Comment: I am not here to entertain my self . Oracle documentation is not clear . I am pretty much happy with this explanation " The idea of unBound receiver such as String::length is that you’re referring to a method of an object that will be supplied as one of the parameters of the lambda. For example, the lambda expression (String s) -> s.toUpperCase() can be rewritten as String::toUpperCase." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914775/java-8-difference-between-method-reference-bound-receiver-and-unbound-receiver .

Comment: @Raj Gopal Bhallamudi: I’m glad that you are happy with this explanation.

Comment: @Holger . The example of this thread is not duplicate as you showed how to create unbound reference with the help of  BiConsumer interface which was not possible for Consumer interface . You entertained me alot .

Answer (score 1):

The same rules for applying method references apply to standard Java classes like String and also your own classes.  In your example, you have 2 types of usages of method references.  1) Instead of normal invocation `doit` and 2) Replacing a lambda expression.

1. The notation in Java 8 `Myclass::doit` means you are calling the static method `doit` on `Myclass`. Instead you have to create an object for `Myclass` and call it on your object as follows:

   ```
   Myclass reallyMyClass = new Myclass();

   Consumer<List<String>> m2 = reallyMyClass::doit;
   m2.accept(obj);
   ```
2. When using method references to replace a lambda, the notation is slightly different and references can be used using the name of the class.  So the usage with String in your example when expanded means:

   ```
   Arrays.sort(arr, (s1, str) -> s1.compareToIgnoreCase(str));
   ```

   and the shorthand version of that replaces the definitions of the lambda parameters and calls the method on `s1` using parameter `str` as the argument to `compareToIgnoreCase` hence having this:

   ```
   Arrays.sort(arr, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
   ```

For further reference, this blog post is a good read on this subject: https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx

Comment: I expected this answer but when String::compareToIgnoreCase is doing the trick then why Myclass::doit cannot ? I mean to say String is also  a class and compareToIgnoreCase is an instance method . How can a class call the instance method instead of static method .

Comment: Edited the answer to have an explanation to that. Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer helped me to solve the problem "create an object for Myclass and call it on your object" . I have the equivalent lambda expression also .                                                                                              ----Consumer<List<String>> m2 =(s)->{System.out.println(s);}; 
m2.accept(obj); ---                                                                                   
but I want to say that String::compareToIgnoreCase is violating the rule . since compareToIgnoreCase is a non static method .