# How to use method reference in Java 8 for Map merge?

Tags: dictionary, merge, java-8, collectors

I have following 2 forms of calling a collect operation, both return same result, but I still cannot depend fully on method references and need a lambda.

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
          BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator,
          BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

For this consider the following stream consisting on 100 random numbers

```
List<Double> dataList = new Random().doubles().limit(100).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1) Following example uses pure lambdas

```
Map<Boolean, Integer> partition = dataList.stream()
            .collect(() -> new ConcurrentHashMap<Boolean, Integer>(),
(map, x) ->
{
    map.merge(x < 0.5 ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE, 1, Integer::sum);
}, (map, map2) ->
{
    map2.putAll(map);
});
```

2) Following tries to use method references but 2nd argument still requires a lambda

```
Map<Boolean, Integer> partition2 = dataList.stream()
            .collect(ConcurrentHashMap<Boolean, Integer>::new, 
(map, x) ->
{
    map.merge(x < 0.5 ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE, 1, Integer::sum);
}, Map::putAll);
```

How can I rewrite 2nd argument of collect method in java 8 to use method reference instead of a lambda for this example?

```
System.out.println(partition.toString());
System.out.println(partition2.toString());
{false=55, true=45}
{false=55, true=45}
```

Comment: Why `map2.putAll(map)`? It should be `map.putAll(map2)`. Look at the [Java 9 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-). Also, you can't use a method reference for the 2nd argument because you have the conditional operator (which btw is unnecessary, it's enough with `x < 0.5`), and an initial `1` as the value to put in the map is there's no entry for the given key.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have tested and using map.putAll(map2) works good. So instead of merge operation, is there a way to call a method reference to increase true key when x <0.5? can you show an example?

Comment: What's wrong with using a lambda? You can't use a method reference when the number and types of the parameters don't match. In this case, `merge` expects 3 arguments: the key, the initial value and a merge binary operator, while the accumulator is a `BiConsumer` that receives the map and an element of the stream and returns nothing. If you create a `void` method that receives the map and an element of the stream, you can use it as a method reference. But I think it's pointless, the lambda is more expressive, IMO

Comment: `putAll` is not a correct merge function for your operation, as it simply overwrites existing mappings instead of merging the values. Further `x < 0.5 ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE` is obsolete. Just use `x < 0.5`. There's no need for a `ConcurrentMap` either. And the entire operation can be performed as simple as: `Map<Boolean, Long> partition2 = dataList.stream() .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> x < 0.5, Collectors.counting()));`

Comment: Thanks for the response Holger, that's much more concise and easier to understand than all that I tried. I'll accept that as the valid answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method reference is a handy tool if you have an existing method doing exactly the intended thing. If you need adaptations or additional operations, there is no special syntax for method references to support that, except, when you consider lambda expressions to be that syntax.

Of course, you can create a new method in your class doing the desired thing and create a method reference to it and that’s the right way to go when the complexity of the code raises, as then, it will get a meaningful name and become testable. But for simple code snippets, you can use lambda expressions, which are just a simpler syntax for the same result. Technically, there is no difference, except that the compiler generated method holding the lambda expression body will be marked as “synthetic”.

In your example, you can’t even use `Map::putAll` as merge function, as that would overwrite all existing mappings of the first map instead of merging the values.

A correct implementation would look like

```
Map<Boolean, Integer> partition2 = dataList.stream()
    .collect(HashMap::new, 
             (map, x) -> map.merge(x < 0.5, 1, Integer::sum),
             (m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((k, v) -> m1.merge(k, v, Integer::sum)));
```

but you don’t need to implement it by yourself. There are appropriate built-in collectors already offered in the `Collectors` class:

```
Map<Boolean, Long> partition2 = dataList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> x < 0.5, Collectors.counting()));
```